# jQuery mobile app doesn't work on Android app created using PhoneGap

Tags: android-layout, jquery-mobile, phonegap-build, phonegap

I am trying to create a form on Android using Phonegap however,  jQuery mobile doesn't work on it. It works if I load straightly from PhoneGap server. The UI of the app is just plain HTML. I have tried all the solutions already on Stackoverflow but I can't seem to figure out the actual problem.

[image: You can see the difference. When loading from PhoneGap server it works but not on android emulator.]

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js">
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="index">
    <fieldset><legend><h1>RentalZ</h1></legend>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-content">
        <form id="rentalzform">
        <label>Property Type: </label>
        <select name="propertyType">
            <option value="House">House</option>
            <option value="Flat">Flat</option>
            <option value="Bungalow">Bungalow</option>
        </select><br><br>
        <label>Bedroom: </label>
        <select name="bedrooms">
            <option value="Studio">Studio</option>
            <option value="One">One</option>
            <option value="Two">Two</option>
            <option value="Three">Three</option>
            <option value="Four">Four</option>
            <option value="Five">5</option>
        </select><br><br>
        <label>Date and Time: </label> <br><br>
        <label>Monthly Rent (£): </label>
        <input type="number" min="0" step="any" name="rent"><br><br>
        <label>Furniture Type: </label>
        <select name="furnitureType">
            <option value="-">-</option>
            <option value="Furnished">Furnished</option>
            <option value="PartlyFurnished">Partly Furnished</option>
            <option value="Unfurnished">Unfurnished</option>
        </select><br><br>
        <textarea rows="4" cols="30">Add Any Notes Here!</textarea><br><br>
        <label>Name: </label>
        <input type="text"  name="name" required><br><br>
        <button onclick="showConfirm()">Click Here!</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    </fieldset>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you get any exceptions?
is it missing formatting files (.css...)

Comment: I do not get any errors. The UI just don't load as expected when using JQuery mobile.

Comment: by UI does not load, you mean formatting?  Are you sure your stylesheet gets loaded properly?  Is it accessible by web? could it be an https issue?

Comment: I mean the formatting.  It is not an https issue.  Just checked it.